# Universal but another word

Tags: vocabulary

I’ve been looking for a word for when something is created which can be enjoyed by both the general public and those with esoteric taste. I’ve been told the word is universal but tbh I don’t find that very satisfying. To me universal appeal means that something can be enjoyed by a very diverse audience. I want a word for a created work that contains subtle brilliance deeply embedded within a generally appealing or agreeable context. This need not strictly pertain to art. Politicians often do this as their communications have to make sense to a general audience but also signal specific actors.

Comment: Please supply a sample sentence with the word you want left blank.

Comment: I don't think there's a word that I would use for dog whistling that I would also use for art

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/universal

Comment: @Dan The Fed chair is speaking  ______ to console the public while simultaneously signal market movers.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **multilayered**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/multilayered) has

> Having or involving several or many layers.

With these examples

> As a result, when you go to make a film you should approach it as though you were about to craft, from scratch, a major, multilayered text.
>
> His patter is one extended verbal riff, multilayered and often hilarious: it has more in common with stand-up comedy than with traditional talk radio.
>
> Her work is colourful, poignant and multilayered.

Of course, the word can be applied to physical things too.

Answer (score 0):

***Inclusive***:

> covering or including everything
> open to everyone : not limited to certain people
> including the stated limits and everything in between ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inclusive))

Comment: Could you please explain why you need a single word in this context?  What is wrong with the words you have used in the question?